# In ASP.net core Identity (UserManager & SignInManager) is it possible to ban a user immediately?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to find a way to provide an administrator of the application I'm developing with an effective way to quickly lockout a user who has either left the company or has been identified as behaving in a way that would warrant an immediate lockout or use of the application.

So far it looks like I can;

```
//enable the account to be locked out
_userManager.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(ApplicationUser user, true);

//Set an arbitrary date way into the future to lock them out until I want to unlock them
_userManager.SetLockoutEndDateAsync(ApplicationUser user, "01/01/2060");
```

But the above doesn't resolve if the user has a cookie with an expiration time of 30 min.  Meaning, the user can continue to use the app if they have already authenticated and are within the default time I'm using for cookies to remain valid.

Is there a user manager method that changes the 'check' that cookie is bounced against?  I'm assuming the [Authorize] attribute tag is checking the cookie against something within Identity that is not exposed in the table.  Wondering how I change the 'check' values so that they don't match cookie session?

Comment: There's nothing in Identity framework that can invalidate a user like this. It shouldn't be too hard to write some middleware that does it though.

Comment: @DavidG  Thanks, any idea what exactly I could update so that when [Authorize] is encountered the values its validating are different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this with some middleware that runs against every request. First create your middleware class, something like this:

```
public class UserDestroyerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public UserDestroyerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext,
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpContext.User.Identity.Name))
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(httpContext.User.Identity.Name);

            if (user.LockoutEnd > DateTimeOffset.Now)
            {
                //Log the user out and redirect back to homepage
                await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
                httpContext.Response.Redirect("/");
            }
        }
        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

And an extension to make it easy to configure:

```
public static class UserDestroyerMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseUserDestroyer(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<UserDestroyerMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

And now in your `Configure` method in `Startup.cs`, add this line after `Identity` has been set up:

```
app.UseUserDestroyer();
```

Now this middleware should run on every request checking if the user should be logged out. You may want to streamline this process by making it not hit the database on every request and instead use some sort of cached list of recently deleted users.

Comment: Nice solution!  I'm just surprised that there's no way to alter the value that the cookie value is bounced against so that the normal authorization process can be leveraged.  It would be nice to know what [authorize] is actually doing under the covers but I can't find any good documentation outside of 'implementation'.

Comment: Well the cookie is held in the users browser so you would never be able to change that. The code for things like [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) is available on GitHub, it's certainly worth taking a look in there.

Comment: I'm working on an application that leverages Identity 3 cookie based authorization, roles that map to users and claims to roles where policies check for claims.  Claims are stored in the cookie where my cookie session is the default 30min. If I change a users role, that user cant access resources that are wrapped by Policies with claims that the role has until the users cookie expires and or they log out and back in. It would be nice if Identity had a method to _userManager.LogOutUserAsync(user). This way the cookie gets reset with the new values from claims being +/- as well as the lockout.

Comment: Did you end up using this code (or a variant of it)?

Comment: Not yet, wondering what the performance impact is.  I also posted a larger concern in a different post surrounding the cookie storing claims for 'x' period of time.  Hoping to find a solution for all.  That said, the above solution seems like a great approach. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378305/asp-net-core-identity-force-user-sign-in-next-request

Comment: Well like I mentioned in my answer, if performance is a concern here, then you would likely benefit from caching of some sort. Maybe even Redis for example if you have a high volume site.

Comment: Any idea how to determine performance impact for something like this?  If say there's 1k users a day sending requests, thats 1k users x N* requests...  How do you determine when something like Redis should be leveraged?

Comment: The only way you can determine that is by load testing your app.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to mark this as an acceptable answer.  I don't know if I'll be using this solution that you provided, but I appreciate it and it looks as though it would do the job!

Comment: For info, it does work - I ended up testing it because I've not written my own middleware yet.

Answer (score 0):

I got to thinking about this a bit more thanks to @DavidG's aproach.

In almost every controller, I have to get the user in order to resolve if the user belongs to the Host user group, a specific Tenant user group, and/or add the user as an editor in a field such as EditedBy if I'm working with an object that is being updated.

This got me thinking that instead of;

```
var user = _userManager.GetUserByEmail(User.Identity.Name);

var hostId = user.HostId;
```

or

```
var tenantId = user.TenantId;
```

or

```
var EditedBy = user.Email;
```

I could create a class that gets the user, but also checks the user object for status changes such as 'LockoutEnd > Today', or ClaimsHaveBeenUpdated.

So here's a different approach that I came up with to alleviate two db calls on every request.

Controller Method

```
var user = _userManager.GetUserByEmail(User.Identity.Name);
```

Repository

```
public async Task<ApplicationUser> GetUserByEmailAsync(string email)
    {
       var user =  await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>x.Email.Equals(email));

        if(user.LockoutEnd > DateTimeOffset.Now )
        {
            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        }
        if (user.CookieStateHasChanged)
        {
            user.CookieStateHasChanged = false;
            await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);

        }
        return user;
    }
```

Unfortunately I'm already calling the Db for the user on every controller GET method to resolve if its a tenant or host user before performing additional business logic. So by adding the extra code above to the GetUserByEmailAsync method in my repo that I DI into the controllers constructor, I can also handle the user claim changes by either refreshing the cookie  or signing out the user if they are locked out.

Keep in mind, if role changes, I'll have to update user.CookieStateHasChange = true.

And when a user is 'disabled' via the UI, I'm updating the user.LockoutEnd  to 10 years+ down the road.

Answer (score 0):

I think a rather simple approach would be creating a filter for this. 
Maybe inheriting `Authorize` attribute and checking a lockout flag for the current user. It'll work for previous versions of asp.net too.