# Asp.net Core Identity 'Force User Sign In Next Request'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

Working on an application that is leveraging Identity 3 in asp.net core.  I have a situation where we are providing sysAdmin needs via a UI to a user to manage users, roles and claims.

Workflow;

1. Roles are dynamically created by the sysAdmin during the setup process of the application where claims (we are calling them permissions in the UI) are assigned to roles.
2. New users are created by sysAdmin where a role is assigned to a user.
3. Claim's are registered with Policies in Startup.cs
4. Policies are scattered throughout the app in the views and controllers to restrict/grant users access based on the claims they have via the roles they are assigned to.
5. Admin can lockout the user via the UI checkbox where the lockout date field in the User table is set way into the future, and reset if they unlock to todays date.

Issue:
The cookie is used to authenticate the user and the claims in the cookie (I think...) are used to authorize the user access to specific resources governed by the policies.  The cookie session is set to the default 30 minutes.

If the admin locks out the user and or if the admin changes the users role, which changes the users claims (+/-)... the changes don't take effect (from a UX) until the user either a. logs out and back in or b. the cookie in their browser expires.

Identity doesn't seem to have a _userManager.ForceUserToSignInAgainAsync() method so that the cookie variables are updated.  Has anyone found a solution for this need?  Seems like a common scenario that should be part of Identity 3.

Comment: Are you looking for logout everywhere if a user's credential is updated?

Comment: I'm looking for an effective way to force the user (who's credentials have changed) to have to log back in as soon as their credentials have changed.  Use case: if the user is logged in, but the admin has 'locked them out', or added or subtracted claims by altering the roles, the next request from the user isn't authenticated forcing them to be redirected to the login page where their cookie is reset with the latest credentials.

Comment: I would think that there would be a bool field in the user table that could be checked so that every time a user's request encounters an [Authorize] attribute, it checks to see if they are 'locked out'.  This way it would redirect them to the sign in page to reset the cookie with updated credentials... but there's not...  there's a 'can be locked out' field and a 'locked out until' date.  But the 'locked out until' date is only checked on login where the cookie is set for x period of time.  The cookie hold the keys to the kingdom, need to find a way to alter whatever is checking the cookie.